# Tricky MySQL query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Ok, help needed!

**table rounds**

```
id|blobs|total
```

**table data**

```
id|roundid|score
```

There are 18 roles in the data table, with the roundid relating to the id of the rounds table.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
update rounds set blobs=count(*) where score=-1
update rounds set total = sum(score) where score != -1
```

Basically find a query to call the total count where score = -1, and the total where score != -1 relating to that round.

Possible, or do I need to look through every round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the needed values with a sub query:

```
UPDATE `rounds` r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT d.roundid,
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.score = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS blobs, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN d.score != -1 THEN d.score ELSE 0 END) AS total
    FROM `data` d
    GROUP BY d.roundid
  ) T1 on (T1.roundid = r.id)
SET r.blobs = T1.blobs, 
     r.total = T1.total
```

Comment: Close, but not sure this will do it.  The count of blobs is only those where score = -1, and the total is the sum of those rows that != -1.

Comment: Sorry missed the difference, I have updated the query